# Postgresql : Euclidian distance between array (in a json row) and an input array

Tags: postgresql, distance

Here is the structure of my database:

field data json in my database postgres for example:

{"field1": [1, 2, 3, 4], "field2": "toto"}
I have another array

array_compare = [5, 6, 7, 8]
Here what I want to do: return a float from data->field1 ( an array) and array_compare by using this formula :

SUM((data->field1 - array_compare)^2))^(1/2) 
I have tried to do many things I have not managed to do it.
In fact, its a way to compute the euclidian distance between an array (in a JSON, need to be cast I guess) and an input array

Sincerly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're probably looking for the [`ROWS FROM` syntax for table functions](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/queries-table-expressions.html#QUERIES-TABLEFUNCTIONS) that has "*the results returned in parallel columns*". You'd use it with [`json_array_elements`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/functions-json.html#FUNCTIONS-JSON-PROCESSING-TABLE) for the JSON array and `unnest` for the normal array.

```
SELECT id, (
  SELECT sum(sqrt(x^2 - y::numeric^2)) -- try `array_agg(x || ' ' || y)` for debugging
  FROM ROWS FROM (
    unnest(ARRAY[5, 6, 7, 8]),
    json_array_elements_text(json->'field1')
  ) as r(x, y)
) as distance
FROM example
```

([online demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=9905839b2e17684b54fbad8fefc4a732))

Answer (score 0):

it should work using the `unnest` function in postgres to get a table where you can then apply the calculations, see https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/functions-array.html

```
unnest(anyarray)    setof anyelement    expand an array to a set of rows    unnest(ARRAY[1,2])
```

Then you should be able to do something like

```
SELECT
    unnest(array[1,2,3]) AS unnest_1,
    unnest(array['a','b','c']) AS unnest_2;
```

would produce

```
 unnest_1 | unnest_2 
----------+----------
        1 | a
        2 | b
        3 | c
(3 ROWS)
```

(Example taken from https://www.depesz.com/2013/11/24/waiting-for-9-4-support-multi-argument-unnest-and-table-syntax-for-multiple-functions/).
Then you can just do regular SQL to get the difference and sum it up.

Comment: If you have two arrays, using `unnest(array1, array2)` is probably simpler

Comment: ah, right, I missed that you linked an article that explains all this in detail (and states the multi-argument `unnest` is a 9.4 feature)! But given the OP didn't state which release he uses, I don't think it matters